# Android Rejected Version because of old bundles permissions

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

I have currently created a new release for an app that I am working on. The release has been rejected because in a way older version I added BACKGROUND_LOCATION to permissions. I tried every tutorial I could find, but I can not delete the bundle that contains the location permission. It is also worth mentioning that the bundle that contains the permission was in the testing channel, not in the release one. Without deleting it, I can not create another release without being rejected. Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Latest one, but it has surely has nothing to do with the version of RN, the bundle works perfectly, has the background-location permission removed form Manifest, but it gets rejected because of the older bundle that contains the BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission.

Comment: Metoo: APK:50 rejected, but reason given in Email is APK:45 "Prominent disclosure not found"! I just filed an appeal. I also used background-location before, but that seems not to be the problem. Do you have a mismatch of the APK:versions in the reason for your rejection, too?